# explicit matrix example of irreducible representation of s0(3)

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Can someone give me a concrete or an explicit example of an irreducible representation of the Lie algebra so$(3)$? I know they are given by the Wigner D matrices but I want an explicit example of such a matrix and if possible how to compute it.

Comment: The defining representation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper

V. M. Gordienko:
Matrix entries of real representations of the group $O(3)$ and $SO(3)$,
Siberian Mathematical Journal (2002), 43(1):36-46,
doi: [10.1023/A:1013816403253](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1013816403253)

describes the construction of the real representations of the Lie group $SO(3)$ using homogeneous polynomials. From those the corresponding representation matrices of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ can be derived, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356141/real-representations-of-lie-algebra-mathfrakso3) and [there](http://visuallietheory.blogspot.de/2013/07/real-representations-of-lie-algebra.html) for explicit examples in dimension 5 and 7.